# I losed reference with <script> in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying execute a var in a `<script>` but I get error

**In the beginning** I had:

```
var cadena = procesarComponenteMultiProductoAsistente(JSON.pasos);
cadena += abrirDivConId("js-spp-assistant") + cerrarDiv();
document.getElementById(JSON.areaCarga).innerHTML += cadena;

document.getElementById(JSON.areaCarga).innerHTML += cadena;
var ele = document.getElementById(JSON.areaCarga);
var codes = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
    eval(codes[i].text);
}
```

with this code I generated a tag

```
<script>
var optionsAssistant = ALL my JSON;
sppWizard.init(optionsAssistant);
</script>
```

Then with -> eval() execute this script with

```
 sppWizard.init(optionsAssistant);
```

The problem is that I can't use eval(...

Then I changed this for ->

Index->

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html class="no-js" lang="es">
    <head>
        <script src="transform_multiproducto_asistente.js"></script>
            <script>
        function run(){
            cargarMultiProductoAsistente();
            sppWizard.init(optionsAssistant); // I try execute now.
        }
        </script>
    </head>
     <body class="spp-loading" onload="run()">
        <main class="spp-main">
            <article id="zona_despliegue">
            </article>
        </main>
        <div id="generateScript">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

`cargarMultiProductoAsistente();` this Get JSON from my Server, Json have datas[links,img,etc], I created a var with this datas.

---

```
sppWizard.init(optionsAssistant); It is a function from my company, Execute the (var);
```

---

```
var cadenaScript = generarScriptAsistente(JSON);
document.getElementById("generateScript").innerHTML += cadenaScript;


var cadena = procesarComponenteMultiProductoAsistente(JSON.pasos);
cadena += abrirDivConId("js-spp-assistant") + cerrarDiv();
document.getElementById(JSON.areaCarga).innerHTML += cadena;
```

---

```
index.html:54 Uncaught ReferenceError: optionsAssistant is not defined
 at run (index.html:54)
 at onload (index.html:58)
```

Comment: You get the JSON from the server..... So what is `cargarMultiProductoAsistente` doing?

Comment: your `index.html` doesn't have 54 lines...

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski I generated code dynamic with my JSON

Comment: @epascarello, this function created the content the my html, You can my html empty, The Html is generated with my JSON